# Julia - How to Import Part of Package and call Using this package?

Tags: package, julia, using

I wanted to use ProgressMeter (for progress bars) and DataStructures (for orderedDicts) in Julia v1.1:

```
using ProgressMeter
using DataStrctures
```

However, both of these packages export an `update!` method.
So I had a warning telling me to specify from which package it comes from and tried to fix it by :

```
ProgressMeter.update!(...)
```

I didn't want it to specify it at each update! in my code, so I decided that I want to only use DataStructures.OrderedDict.

However, when I do this with import :

```
import DataStructures.OrderedDict
```

I can't call `using DataStructures` after this to avoid `DataStructures.{OrderedDict, or something linked to orderedDict}` each time I use OrderedDict as `using` imports everything on DataStructures and re-enter in conflicts with the update! from ProgressMeter.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly bring `update!` from `ProgressMeter` into scope.

```
using DataStructures
using ProgressMeter
using ProgressMeter: update!
```

Now there should be no warning and `update!` alone should refer to the methods in `ProgressMeter`. If you need to call the `update!` in `DataStructures`, you should qualify it with the name `DataStructures`.

Comment: When I do this I get a warning :
"WARNING: using DataStructures.update! in module Main conflicts with an existing identifier"

Comment: Have you tried it at the beginning of your file? Because if you have already referred to `update!` before `using ProgressMeter` and then try to change the binding, it will ignore it and will still give you warnings.